# How can I show title header and paragraph in the same order as the original web page? - Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, wikipedia

I am parser a wikipedia web page. 
I want to search a keyword for example  "The first abstraction" and show tittle, header, and paragraph where it matched, How can i do it?.

```
Web :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics
Search = "The first abstraction"
Output :
       tittle: Mathematics
       header: History
       paragraph : The history of mathematics can be seen as an ever-increasing series of   
                   abstractions. **The first abstraction**, which is shared by many animals,[14] was 
                   probably that of numbers: the realization that a collection of two apples and a            
                   collection of two oranges (for example) have something in common, namely quantity 
                   of their members. 
import bs4
import requests

response = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics")

if response is not None:
html = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

title = html.select("#firstHeading")[0].text
print(title)
paragraphs = html.select("p")
for para in paragraphs:
    print (para.text)

# just grab the text up to contents as stated in question
intro = '\n'.join([ para.text for para in paragraphs[0:5]])
print (para.text)
```

This code shows the title well, but the header and paragraph are not ordered and then i can´t matched it.
Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to search for "The first abstraction" when you are looping through

tags, as you only want the paragraph that has "The first abstraction".

So add a find() method on your 'para' to check if the expected text is present or not -

```
paragraphs = html.select("p")

Search = "The first abstraction" # expected text

for para in paragraphs:
    px = para.text
    if px.find(Search)>-1:
        print (para.text)
```

This will give you the expected paragraph as -

```
The history of mathematics can be seen as an ever-increasing series of abstractions. The first abstraction, which is shared by many animals,[14] was probably that of numbers: the realization that a collection of two apples and a collection of two oranges (for example) have something in common, namely quantity of their members.
```

So now the *paragraph* and *title* is done. You need to extract *header*.
Focus on the html file structure of the page you're trying to parse (this will always help) .

In the below image, **h2** is a sibling to the **p** tag (where your text was found). Read about siblings [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling).

[image]

So to traverse to the immediate previous sibling, you should call 'previous_sibling' twice on **p** tag.

As **h2** is a sibling 2 tags prior to **p**, you could access **h2** (which has 'History' header) as -

```
paragraphs = html.select("p")
for para in paragraphs:
    px = para.text
    if px.find(Search)>-1:
        print (para.text)
        print(para.previous_sibling.previous_sibling.previous_sibling.previous_sibling.text)
```

This will print -

```
History
```